# How can I enable HDMI Sound on a AMD/ATI HD9550

Tags: 11.10, hdmi, ati

I have a computer with an AMD HD9550 graphic card. I want to output the sound to my TV by HDMI. But I cannot get it to work.

I Have tried config the sound options. And I am not using the additional driver.

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67113/fast-video-playback-with-no-sound

Comment: There is no HDMI option in my sound setting output. How can I add one?

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the Sound Preferences (click the volume applet and select Sound Settings. Make sure that in the Hardware tab, HDMI is selected as the profile. Also make sure HDMI is selected under the output tab.

Otherwise you may need to install the fglrx driver