# Open Source ATI Driver and HDMI support

Tags: ati, hdmi

(**Note** : This question may also concern every owner of a *brand new* [ATI legacy](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?70500-AMD-To-Drop-Radeon-HD-2000-3000-4000-Catalyst-Support) card!)

I have an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670 on my laptop and I installed Ubuntu 12.10 a few months ago. Since then, I've been looking for some way to make the HDMI work, as the proprietary drivers [do not work with the new Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203232/radeon-hd-2000-3000-4000-on-12-10-quantal-fglrx-legacy-12-6-unsupported-wh).

Recently, I came across [this post](http://fixunix.com/linux/264623-%5Bnews%5D-open-source-ati-amd-driver-gains-hdmi-support.html) from 2007. Am I missing something? Is it *possible* to make the HDMI sound port work with the open source ATI driver? Is there some work around without having to install some [obscure kernel](http://forum.pinguyos.com/Thread-HOW-TO-ATI-HDMI-audio-with-open-source-driver) or [unsupported PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emakson96/+archive/fglrx)?

When I execute the `lspci` command, I do get the lines

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV635 [Mobility Radeon HD 3670]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV635 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 3600 Series]
```

which tells me that it *can* be used to send audio through it, but it does not appear in my Sound Settings.

** **Note** ** : It seems that Redhat ([Bug 428964](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=428964)) has a patch that works with some ATI cards (including mine), why hasn't this ended up in the Ubuntu release? (Or if it did, why doesn't it work anymore?)

** **Note 2** ** : Even [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI) has some documentation to install HDMI support with the open source ATI drivers!

---

#### Supplement

The HDMI cable is plugged in, I even rebooted the computer and tried under serval conditions, the following information are constant : The command `aplay -l` returns

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And finally `aplay -D plughw:1,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`... just does nothing.

Also, [this looked quite promising](http://mylifewithcomputers.blogspot.ca/2011/12/ubuntu-and-hdmi.html), but I hesitate to install PulseAudio.

Another [forum discussion](http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/17997/3052/) that looks interesting, but I lack some understanding on this one right now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast video playback with no sound](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67113/fast-video-playback-with-no-sound)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following helped me to get hdmi audio back (Ubuntu 12.10; Radeon HD 4800):

It is also notable that the open source driver for ATI/AMD (called radeon), has experimental support for HDMI/DisplayPort audio, at least for some cards. It is disabled by default, but you can activate it by adding `radeon.audio=1` as a [kernel boot parameter](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) \:

1. Run **`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`** and add the parameter to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. For example:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"
   ```
2. Run **`sudo update-grub`**.
3. Reboot.

Comment: I edited your answer. I already had the kernel parameter set, but just forgot to update grub! When you wrote that it worked for you, I double checked and realized my mistake. All is well now!

Comment: I did the same thing but still Audio still not working (kernel 3.8, ati HD4570).    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1 acpi_osi=Linux pcie_aspm=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="persistent acpi.power_nocheck=1 radeon.agpmode=-1 radeon.pcie_gen2=1 radeon.hw_i2c=1 radeon.msi=1 radeon.modeset=1"

Comment: Here is the corresponding bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/864735