# No HDMI audio in 13.04

Tags: sound, hdmi

I have just upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04 and now everything works perfectly, except the fact that I have no audio via HDMI.

I am using a Samsung tv-monitor connected via HDMI to my video card Asus EAH4670/DI/1GD3 (which has a Radeon HD 4670 gpu on it), installed phisically into my motherboard which is a MSI 770-C45. I am running kernel 3.9, I just have no sound.

I tried downloading and installing https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+files/oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201304261252~raring1_all.deb , but without any good result.

Please help, I need my audio back. In the end, this is my lspci command output.

```
ale@beast:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RX780/RX790 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port C)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV730 XT [Radeon HD 4670]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV710/730 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4000 series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
ale@beast:~$
```

Comment: The Radeon  driver doesn't provide HDMI audio, if you want HDMI audio you have to install Catalyst. Make sure you install the Legacy driver since AMD dropped support for the Radeon HD 4xxx series.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised I had this problem after reading this post.

I followed this page to update my kernel, which fixed the problem:
https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme

As for the kernel update not fixing the problem in your case, be sure you've checked all the possibilities like for example that the volume is not muted. Also you could try creating a new user account and loggin in with that, too see if the problem is localised to bad settings in your user profile.

If you haven't actually checked that the kernel has been updated, open a terminal and type uname -r.
I'm using kernel 3.9.0-030900-generic.

If that doesn't work, then reinstalling 13.04 fresh and installing the new kernel, would be the final step to ensure that all other possibilities are ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

You have an ATI graphics card, did you try the `radeon.audio=1` kernel parameter? See [No sound on HDMI with Radeon driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67113/no-sound-on-hdmi-with-radeon-driver).