# 13.10 - PulseAudio puts audio into HDMI, but no sound out of TV

Tags: sound, ati, pulseaudio, hdmi, alsa

Basically, no sound is coming out the television. I'm running out of idea of why?

Viewing the PulseAudio control panel, it's putting sound out the HDMI

[image]

Alsamixer is not mute

[image]

The Television is not mute. I booted into Windows and the audio out the HDMI works fine.

[image]

## Debugging Info:

**Basics**

- Xubuntu 13.10
- Linux desktop 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP
- ATI 4870

**lshw -c video**

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV770 [Radeon HD 4870]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:44 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:feae0000-feaeffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:feac0000-feadffff
```

**aplay -l**

```
   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
   card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
     Subdevices: 0/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
     Subdevices: 1/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
     Subdevices: 0/1
     Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**sudo speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:1,3**

```
   speaker-test 1.0.27.1

   Playback device is hw:1,3
   Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
   Using 16 octaves of pink noise
   Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy
```

Comment: In case you use the open source radeon driver you may need to enable HDMI audio with a Grub setting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67113/no-sound-on-hdmi-with-radeon-driver

Comment: @Takkat that worked perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad you got it running :) +1 for the extremely well written question, but we probably have to close it as a dupe to the question I linked to.