# ATI HD5450 not playing sound over HDMI om Ubuntu 12.04.5

Tags: drivers, sound, ati, hdmi

I have been battling with a major problem with my ATI card and getting sound to come out of the HDMI port to my TV. The card is a HD5450 by MSI and im using it in a HP Proliant Microserver. I installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 Server and put no-recommends-ubuntu-desktop on the machine. I then proceeded to install the ATI drivers from ubuntu software center and then installed Kodi. For the first run all was well. After restarting I could no longer find the soundcard on the graphics card (HDMI).

I tried "aplay -l" and get no sound card detected. I tried "aticonfig --intial" and all seems well however still no sound card.

I have tried all solutions I have seen on the Ask-ubuntu pages and none seems to work for me or the problem is not exactly the same.

I am thinking there are sound drivers (xorg etc) that are stopping the fglrx to be the main driver...

Any help will be appreciated.

I have also tried this solution here with no luck. [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67113/no-sound-on-hdmi-with-radeon-driver)

The main issue with my problem is no sound card is being detected at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with a very similar graphics card (HD5540D), I think I never make it work 100%.
When I installed some drivers fglrx and xorg I think, had a lot of problems because a lot of times wouldn't boot up Ubuntu.
Image worked pretty good with vga (didn't test it with hdmi or dvi), and I got the sound out apart with a normal jack in the rear panel of my motherboard.

You could try getting the sound on an external speaker if you can.

Although I'm talking about 2013 Ubuntu's versions, this information could be useful to you.

Hope it helped

Comment: Does not really answer the question nor solve. But thanks for the attempt.

Comment: I know, but I told you some things to be aware of (like to be careful of the video drivers), that could help you.

Comment: Yup. As mentioned in the original post.